# Unable to install pyexcel in Anaconda in new environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, pyexcel

Using the command prompt, I installed `pyexcel` using 
`conda install -c conda-forge pyexcel`. I went to Anaconda Navigator and then confirmed that it was installed in the base(root) environment.

After creating a new environment called `envda`, I found that `pyexcel` was not available to `envda`. I even selected "Update index", but the package will still not appear. Then from `envda`, I opened up a terminal window and typed `conda install --name envda pyexcel`, but the error message from conda reports that the package is not available from the channel.

Puzzled by this as it should install the package from the base environment to the new environment being `envda`. Also don't know why in Anaconda Navigator, that pyexcel is not available to be selected for installation in environment envda.

How can I make sure that the package `pyexcel` is installed in my environment `envda`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Puzzled by this as it should install the package from the base environment to the new environment being envda.

This is not how conda works. You need to specify the channel every time you install the package. Conda will avoid downloading the package again, if it can, but it does not automatically "copy" packages from one environment to the other with the `install` command.